# Web server stress testing tool

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a free web server stress testing application/tool/website.
I have used [Paessler Webstress](http://www.paessler.com/webstress/download), it is good enough, but only free with restricted functionality.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nearly impossible to have a web application based around this?  Just from my understanding of how these programs work - don't they install on your server and monitor things on these?  (ie isn't the requirement that something reside on your server to monitor?)

Comment: This is probably better asked at http://ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)? It is software.

I am not aware of any legal stress testing tools such as a web-app, though if you are desperate, you can try renting those spambots machines (joking).

There are a couple of services that do single/double retrieval with detailed statistics. This might be useful to do while you are using JMeter to simulate the rest of the load. See, for example, [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/).

Comment: Yes, Apache JMeter is perfect. I had used it extensively in last 3 months. Here are some good posts to get you started on [Apache JMeter](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/tag/jmeter/).

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I prefer [LoadImpact](http://loadimpact.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) is an application I have used in the past to do some load testing, Its a bit complicated but extremely powerful.

Comment: +1 it seems as a good tool. i will investigate it. thank you!

Comment: While Badboy offers some elementary load testing features, to do real stress testing you often need much more. Rather than trying to offer all of the features of a complete load testing product, Badboy integrates with a free, open source product called JMeter. JMeter is run by the Apache Software Foundation and is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *nix box, Apache Benchmark tool (ab) is likely to be already installed.
See [Apache Benchmark Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)